# R Generating vector w/ random integers in a fixed range with defined sum

Tags: r, vector, random, integer, range

I am trying to put together code which generates a vector any length, containing only randomized integer values within the range 0 to 3 and which total sum is always equal to 100.

I came up with the following code:

```
#Creating variables
x <- NULL
y_vec <- NULL

while(sum(y_vec) < 100) {
x <- sample(0:3,1)
y_vec <- c(y_vec, x) 
if(sum(y_vec) > 100) {
y_vec <- y_vec[-length(y_vec)]
} }

#Checking on the result
sum(y_vec)
y_vec
```

However, I do suppose there is an easier code for this problem. But so far I could not figure out any other way.

Comment: "[...] generates a vector any length [...]". Your min length is determined and is 34.

Comment: Your code is fine: My sugguestion you could sample more values at once. For eg in the first "run" you could sample 33 values. Then sum all and see how many times a 3 would fit in the diff to 100. This is the number of the next "block" ... and so on

Comment: @AndreElrico You are right, the min length is 34. Is there any suggestion on how I could improve the sampling of the last missing value?